# knitr Minimal Demo not compiling correctly

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, knitr, sweave

Hi knitr experts: I cannot for the life of me figure out how to compile the knitr Miminal Demo .Rnw document correctly. When I download and run Yihui's Minimal Demo of knitr .Rnw file ([link](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/examples/knitr-minimal.Rnw)), the document compiles but incorrectly handles the R chunks:

[image: Miscompiled .Rnw Demo]

I changed nothing, just opened and compiled. Help welcome. As an aside, would very much appreciate tips on whether this is how I should be going about adding R code into a latex template that UT-Austin requires for dissertation publication. Thanks.

Comment: Your image is a bit faint, what is on the first page? I seems like it would be relevant. Was there anything on the console when you compiled to PDF?

Comment: Hi r2evans - The first page is the printed content of the first R Chunk: > library(knitr) > opts_chunk$set(fig.path='figure/minimal-', fig.align='center', fig.show='hold') > 
options(formatR.arrow=TRUE,width=90). The console issues two warnings: "The marginal notes overrun the paper" and "you are using breakurl while processing via pdflatex."

Comment: I'm not able to compile the doc myself, though while I do have `tinytex` installed, I do not typically work with Rnw files. I'm not getting a PDF, so my issues are different fro yours. Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. Calling @yihui-xie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce your PDF file when using `Sweave` instead of `knitr` for translating the `.Rnw` file. When switching to `knitr` via the RStudio options (c.f. https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532247), I get an error message and no PDF, which probably reproduces @r2evans' results in the comments. I also get a warning message that line 19 is `Sweave` specific (`\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}`). Removing that line, the file processes with `knitr` correctly producing

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thank you. I still can't get it to work with the school's LaTex template, but this gets me started!